# Make Multiple CheckBox PreChecked on Page Load in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My .html file code is

```
 <label class="col-md-6 pb-6" *ngFor="let job of CheckBoxandLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{job.childid}}" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
</label
```

in My Ts File .

```
CheckBoxandLabel=[{childid = 1},{childid = 2},{childid = 3},{childid = 4}]

PreSelectedCheckbox = [2,4]




onCheckboxChange(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.jobcategoryArray.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
      this.jobcategoryArray.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
        if (item.value == event.target.value) {
          this.jobcategoryArray.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
}
```

So , on PageLoad , i want the value from PreSelectedChecbox i.e 2 and 4

i.e job.childid = 2 & 4 must be preselected

Comment: Why are you adding new FormControl to jobcategoryArray?

Comment: Take a look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scxyer, it may help you

Comment: i want the same with Reactive Forms

Comment: anyone here can solve this